# ACE Service Configurator Framework alternatives

Tags: c++, ace

Are there any frameworks with similar functionality as ACE Service Configurator Framework? Or what approaches do you know to deal with dynamically loaded modules?

Answer (score 0):

We are using ACE, that works the best on all platforms in our experience.